# Change Superuser name in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, root

I mistyped my superuser. It should be "masi" instead of "maasi". I do not want to configure and install all packages again. How can I change it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're not talking about UID 0 (which is almost always called root, and probably hardcoded as that name in a few admin applications), then the 'super user' is just a user in the `admin` group. You can use the method mentioned above (though make sure you also edit `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/gshadow`, and use `vipw` and `vigr`), but I'd recommend simply creating a new account with the correct name, adding it to the `admin` group (`adduser masi admin`), and migrating your data to it (copying the home directory and `chown -R masi` are probably sufficient). Log in to the new account and confirm that you can run `sudo` before deleting the old account. This is much less likely to leave you locked out of your system.

Answer (score 5):

You will want to use the [`usermod`](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/usermod.htm) command. It will update all files needed for you as well.

You must make note of the caveats though:

> CAVEATS:
>
> usermod will not allow you to change
>   the name of a user who is logged in.
>   You must make certain that the named
>   user is not executing any processes
>   when this command is being executed if
>   the user's numerical user ID is being
>   changed. You must change the owner of
>   any crontab files manually. You must
>   change the owner of any at jobs
>   manually. You must make any changes
>   involving NIS on the NIS server.

Answer (score 2):

Just edit the entry in `/etc/password` to what you want. You may also need to update `/etc/group` for consistency. Then rename your home directory (in `/home`) to match.

All file permissions are done by user/group ID (the number associated with your name) so by updating the name, it should "just work".